# Create entity test for Symfony 2 bundle which doesn't have entities: The class was not found in the chain configured namespaces

Tags: testing, symfony, doctrine, bundle

We have created a bundle to integrate CartoDB in Symfony2 projects. This bundle doesn't create any entity itself, because it 'listen' for events such as persist or flush on your own entities to synchronize info between your data and cartodb data. Here is the workflow:

Create an entity object --> persist --> listen event --> add data to cartoDB throught their API --> get cartoDB object id --> update it in your created object

Here is an example for CartoDB Bundle annotations:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="testDB", options={"collate"="utf8_general_ci"})
 * @CartoDB\CartoDBLink(connection="private", table="testDB", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
 */

class TestDB
{
/**
* @ORM\Column(name="cartodb_index", type="integer", nullable=true)
* @CartoDB\CartoDBColumn(column="testdb_id", index=true)
*/
protected $cartodbId;
```

We would like to create tests that cover any part of the code, so we have decided to include an Entity in the test folder to test synchronization with cartoDB data, and add it in the test folder, we have followed this steps:

1. Add Doctrine Bundle to our bundle composer.json.
2. Create an entity class in this route:

---

```
Company/Tests/CartoDB/Entity/TestDB.php
```

This entity looks like this:

```
<?php

namespace Company\CartoDBBundle\Tests\CartoDB\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
* @ORM\Entity
* @ORM\Table(name="testDB", options={"collate"="utf8_general_ci"})
* @CartoDB\CartoDBLink(connection="private", table="testDB", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
*/

class TestDB
{
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;
.....
?>
```

3. Now its turn for the test script. We use the entity namespace:

   use Company\CartoDBBundle\Tests\CartoDB\Entity\TestDB;

Next, we create an entity object:

```
$test = new TestDB();  
$test->setText("HI");
```

It runs ok, we call objects methods and everything goes right, and last pass:

```
$em->persist($test);
$em->flush();
```

> Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\MappingException: The class 'Company\CartoDBBundle\Tests\CartoDB\Entity\TestDB' was not found in the chain configured namespaces

Here is our doctrine configuration:

```
doctrine:  
dbal:  
  driver: pdo_sqlite  
  path: "%kernel.root_dir%/sqlite.db"  
  charset: UTF8  
orm:  
  auto_generate_proxy_classes: %kernel.debug%  
  auto_mapping: true
```

Don't know what we are missing, can anyone help us?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic problem is that by default, Doctrine only looks in the Bundle/Entity directory.  So you need a bit more info under orm: in your configuration file.

The manual has more details: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/doctrine.html

```
doctrine:
orm:
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: %kernel.debug%
    auto_mapping: false
    mappings:
        name:
            type: php
            dir: %kernel.root_dir%/../src/Company/CartoDBBundle/Tests/CartoDB/Entity
          # alias: MyModels
          # prefix: MyBundle\OtherNamespacePart\Entity
          # is_bundle: true
```

You may or may not need to futz around with alias and prefix.  When it's properly configured then running:

```
app/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql
```

Will dump the table information.

Comment: Thanks Cedar, i will read about this configuration parameters.  Only one more thing, we are developing an isolated bundle, this time we dont have app/console to execute those commands, is there another way to get the dump information ?

Comment: Sure.  The Symfony commands are just thin wrappers to the Doctrine commands.  http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/tools.html.