# Symfony 2.5.5 & FOSUserBundle: the class ... was not found in the chain configured namespaces

Tags: symfony, doctrine, mapping, fosuserbundle, mappingexception

Recently, I started working with Symfony2. Now I want to add a user management engine to my site.

But I'm facing a problem. This is what I'm doing:

1. In terms of creating/installing a basic Symfony2 project:

   ```
   $ composer create-project symfony/framework-standard-edition path/ "2.5.*"
   $ mv path/* ./
   $ rm -r path/
   ```
2. Ok, so much for Symfony 2.5.5. Next, download the FOSUserBundle and create a custom bundle:

   ```
   $ composer require friendsofsymfony/user-bundle '~2.0@dev'
   $ php app/console generate:bundle --namespace=Meiblorn/CoreBundle --format=yml
   ```
3. Create the User class in the Meiblorn\CoreBundle\Framework\Domain namespace

   ```
   /**
    * User: Meiblorn
    * Date: 15/10/14
    * Time: 20:17
    */

   namespace Meiblorn\CoreBundle\Framework\Domain;

   use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as FOSUserBundleUser;
   use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

   /**
    * @ORM\Entity
    * @ORM\Table(
    *      name = "users"
    * )
    */
   class User extends FOSUserBundleUser {

       /**
        * @ORM\Id
        * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
        * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
        */
       protected $id;

       public function __construct() {
           parent::__construct();
           // your own logic
       }

   }

   ?>
   ```
4. Configure the security.yml and config.yml. Finally, I got this:

   #### AppKernel.php

   ```
   $bundles = array(
           new Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle(),
           new Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\SecurityBundle(),
           new Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigBundle(),
           new Symfony\Bundle\MonologBundle\MonologBundle(),
           new Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\SwiftmailerBundle(),
           new Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\AsseticBundle(),
           new Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle(),

           new FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserBundle(),

           new Meiblorn\CoreBundle\MeiblornCoreBundle(),
   );
   ```

   #### config.yml

   ```
   imports:
       - { resource: parameters.yml }
       - { resource: security.yml }

   framework:
       #esi:             ~
       translator:      { fallback: "%locale%" }
       secret:          "%secret%"
       router:
           resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing.yml"
           strict_requirements: ~
       form:            ~
       csrf_protection: ~
       validation:      { enable_annotations: true }
       templating:
           engines: ['twig']
           #assets_version: SomeVersionScheme
       default_locale:  "%locale%"
       trusted_hosts:   ~
       trusted_proxies: ~
       session:
           # handler_id set to null will use default session handler from php.ini
           handler_id:  ~
       fragments:       ~
       http_method_override: true

   # Twig Configuration
   twig:
       debug:            "%kernel.debug%"
       strict_variables: "%kernel.debug%"

   # Assetic Configuration
   assetic:
       debug:          "%kernel.debug%"
       use_controller: false
       bundles:        [ ]
       #java: /usr/bin/java
       filters:
           cssrewrite: ~
           #closure:
           #    jar: "%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/compiler.jar"
           #yui_css:
           #    jar: "%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/yuicompressor-2.4.7.jar"

   # Doctrine Configuration
   doctrine:
       dbal:
           driver:   "%database_driver%"
           host:     "%database_host%"
           port:     "%database_port%"
           dbname:   "%database_name%"
           user:     "%database_user%"
           password: "%database_password%"
           charset:  UTF8
       orm:
           auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
           auto_mapping: true

   # Swiftmailer Configuration
   swiftmailer:
       transport: "%mailer_transport%"
       host:      "%mailer_host%"
       username:  "%mailer_user%"
       password:  "%mailer_password%"
       spool:     { type: memory }

   fos_user:
       db_driver: orm
       firewall_name: prod
       user_class: Meiblorn\CoreBundle\Framework\Domain\User
   ```

   #### security.yml

   ```
   security:
           encoders:
               FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: sha512

           role_hierarchy:
               ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
               ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN

           providers:
               fos_userbundle:
                   id: fos_user.user_provider.username

           firewalls:
               prod:
                   pattern: ^/
                   form_login:
                       provider: fos_userbundle
                       csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
                   logout:       true
                   anonymous:    true
               dev:
                   pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
                   security: false

           access_control:
               - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
               - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
               - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
               - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
   ```

## THIS IS THE PROBLEM

```
In browser:  http://localhost/test.meiblorn.com/web/app_dev.php/

MappingException: The class 'Meiblorn\CoreBundle\Framework\Domain\User' was not found in the chain configured namespaces FOS\UserBundle\Model
in /Library/WebServer/Documents/test.meiblorn.com/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/MappingException.php line 37
at MappingException::classNotFoundInNamespaces('Meiblorn\CoreBundle\Framework\Domain\User', array('FOS\UserBundle\Model')) in /Library/WebServer/Documents/test.meiblorn.com/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/Driver/MappingDriverChain.php line 113
at MappingDriverChain->loadMetadataForClass('Meiblorn\CoreBundle\Framework\Domain\User', object(ClassMetadata)) in /Library/WebServer/Documents/test.meiblorn.com/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/ClassMetadataFactory.php line 117
at ClassMetadataFactory->doLoadMetadata(object(ClassMetadata), object(ClassMetadata), false, array()) in /Library/WebServer/Documents/test.meiblorn.com/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/AbstractClassMetadataFactory.php line 318
```

#### Also Doctrine doesn't create tables for this mapping when calling doctrine:schema:update

## Please, help me to fix this exception

---

## UPDATE! How to fix

Final configuration for my namespace

```
orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
        auto_mapping: false
        mappings:
            FOSUserBundle: ~
            MeiblornCoreBundle:
                type: annotation
                dir: %kernel.root_dir%/../src/Meiblorn/CoreBundle/Framework/Entity
                prefix: Meiblorn\CoreBundle\Framework\Entity
              # alias: MyModels
              # is_bundle: true
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need to configure psr-4 autoload in your composer.js, for example

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "Meiblorn\\CoreBundle\\": "src/Meiblorn/CoreBundle/"
    }
},
```

Then call `composer dumpautoload`.

Secondly, I believe Doctrine expects the entities to live in a folder `Entity/`, so try to move you model: `src/Meiblorn/CoreBundle/Framework/Domain/User.php` to `src/Meiblorn/CoreBundle/Entity/User.php` or [How do I change symfony 2 doctrine mapper to use my custom directory instead of my Entity Directory under the bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18503093/how-do-i-change-symfony-2-doctrine-mapper-to-use-my-custom-directory-instead-of)

Comment: Hello. Problem was in "Framework\Domain" subfolders. When I had moved 'Meiblorn\CoreBundle\Framework\Domain\User' to 'Meiblorn\CoreBundle\Entity\User', it worked.

Comment: In question text added the problem solution