# Symfony 3.4 - new security provider

Tags: symfony, security

I try add provider.What I'm doing wrong.

I have entity class, and I would like to extend this class

```
namespace AppBundle\Service;

use AppBundle\Entity\Pracownik;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;


class Userek extends Pracownik implements UserInterface
{
    public function getUsername()
    {
        return $this->getLogin();
    }

    public function getSalt()
    {
        // you *may* need a real salt depending on your encoder
        // see section on salt below
        return null;
    }

    public function getPassword()
    {
        return $this->getLogin();
    }

    public function getRoles()
    {
        return array('ROLE_PRACOWNIK');
    }

    public function eraseCredentials()
    {
    }

    public function isSuperAdmin()
    {
        return false;
    }

}
```

in security.yml i add

```
encoders:
        AppBundle\Service\Userek: plaintext
providers:
    pracownik_db_provider:
        entity:
            class: AppBundle\Service\Userek
            property: login
firewalls:
     main:
          pattern: ^/
          form_login:
              provider: pracownik_db_provider
              login_path: /login
              check_path: /login_check
          logout:
              path: /logout
              target: /login
```

When I try login, i got message:

```
The class 'AppBundle\Service\Userek' was not found in the chain configured namespaces AppBundle\Entity, FOS\UserBundle\Model"
```

If I implements Class Pracownik adding methods from the implemented class without creating an additional new class extending the Pracownik class - works

Comment: User classs is not the same as user provider. https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/security/custom_provider.html

Answer (score 1):

Try to move your `Userek` class to the `AppBundle\Entity\` folder, because Doctrine expects to find model classes on that folder `Entity\`.

Just move `AppBundle\Service\Userek.php` to `AppBundle\Entity\Userek.php` and come back if you still get the error message.

If you want Doctrine use another folder to store your model classes or entities, you can find some help to do that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18503093/how-do-i-change-symfony-2-doctrine-mapper-to-use-my-custom-directory-instead-of) or on the full documentation [Doctrine configurations](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/doctrine.html).